# How append rectangle to QGraphicView

Tags: c++, qt, drawrectangle

How can I append new rectangle shape to `QgraphicView` In this code which create rectangle when the button click.But when I click the button second time previously created rectangle removed.I need to do create 2 rectangle when I click the button 2 times.create 3 rectangle when I click the button 3 times

```
void Widget::on_btnCreateRect_clicked()
{
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);

    //QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(6);

    rect = scene->addRect(-10,-10,100,100,blackPen,blueBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);` you create a new scene and add the rectangle to it. The old scene with the previous rectangles exist but is not shown anymore. So instead of creating a new scene use the old one like that: `rect = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(-10,-10,100,100,blackPen,‌​blueBrush);`. This will also avoid the memory leak you create with `new`. Here is the corrected code:

```
void Widget::on_btnCreateRect_clicked()
{
    //QBrush redBrush(Qt::red);
    QBrush blueBrush(Qt::blue);
    QPen blackPen(Qt::black);
    blackPen.setWidth(6);

    QRect *rect = ui->graphicsView->scene()->addRect(-10,-10,100,100,blackPen,‌​blueBrush);
    rect->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable, true);
}
```